# Python linear least squares fit

Tags: python, python-3.x, least-squares

I have four equations with three unknowns, in the format:

-3.81551272e-06 = -0.56941556x -0.56941556y + 0.5929012z

1.79345261e-06 = 0.56941556x -0.56941556y + 0.5929012z

2.85508570e-06 = -0.56941556x + 0.56941556y + 0.5929012z

5.98321503e-07 = 0.56941556x + 0.56941556y + 0.5929012z

I'm supposed to solve for x,y,z in Python using a linear least squares fit, and now I don't know what to do from here. I've organized the values into numpy arrays A and B because I think I might need to do that first...

```
A = np.array([[-0.56941556, -0.56941556,  0.5929012 ],[ 0.56941556, -0.56941556,  0.5929012 ],[-0.56941556,  0.56941556,  0.5929012 ],[ 0.56941556,  0.56941556,  0.5929012 ]])

B = np.array([-3.81551272e-06,  1.79345261e-06,  2.85508570e-06,  5.98321503e-07])
```

I don't know what to do from here, help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Hint, how would you solve this problem using paper and pencil?  In other words, write down the individual steps you would take to solve the least squares problem .  Once you have the steps defined, look at the steps for special conditions such as repeatable operations, tests for limits, etc.  Once you have done the work, try to implement in code.  Shgow your code and then ask your question..

Comment: What @itporh66 said. Also, have a look at the documentation. It looks like you are using numpy. Who knows, it might have a least-squares solver already implemented for you!(Hint: it does. It's in the linalg submodule.)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
X1 = np.linalg.lstsq(A,B,rcond=None)[0]
print(X1)
```